# Errors creating Oracle package body

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have the following body from my package, used to do some CRUD operations in HR schema:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE emp_sequence;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY employee_crud AS

   PROCEDURE create_emp(p_last_name IN employees.last_name%type, p_first_name IN    employees.first_name%type, 
                             p_email IN employees.email%type, p_hire_date IN  employees.hire_date%type, 
                             p_job_id IN employees.job_id%type) AS


   BEGIN
     SELECT emp_sequence.NEXTVAL INTO id FROM dual;
     INSERT INTO employees(last_name, first_name, email, hire_date, job_id)
     VALUES (emp_seq.nextval, p_last_name, p_first_name, p_email, p_hire_date, p_job_id);
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('error');
   END create_emp;


   PROCEDURE erase_emp(p_employee_id IN employees.employee_id%type) AS
   BEGIN
     DELETE FROM employees
     WHERE employee_id = p_employee_id;
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN  NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('Error');
   END erase_emp;


   PROCEDURE upd_emp(p_employee_id IN employees.employee_id%type, p_salary IN  employees.salary%type, 
                                  p_email IN employees.email%type, p_department_id IN  employees.department_id%type) AS
   BEGIN
     UPDATE employees
     SET  employee_id = p_employee_id,
          salary = p_salary,
          email = p_email,
          department_id = p_department_id
     WHERE employee_id = p_employee_id;
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('error');
   END upd_emp;


   PROCEDURE read_emp(p_employee_id IN employees.employee_id%type, p_last_name OUT  employees.last_name%type, 
                                 p_first_name OUT employees.first_name%type, p_email OUT  employees.email%type, 
                                 p_hire_date OUT  employees.hire_date%type, p_job_id OUT  employees.job_id%type, 
                                 p_salary OUT employees.salary%type) AS
   BEGIN
     SELECT employee_id, last_name, first_name, email, hire_date, job_id, salary
     INTO  p_last_name, p_first_name, p_email, p_hire_date, p_job_id, p_salary
     FROM EMPLOYEES
     WHERE employee_id = p_employee_id;
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('Error');
   END read_emp;

END employee_crud;
/
```

After creating the specification (which is correct), I create a sequence to help adding employees. But compiling the body of the package, it shows the following errors:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ----------------------------------------------------
10/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/38    PLS-00201: 'ID' must be declared
10/41    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : identifier is not valid
11/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
11/17    PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
49/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
51/5     PL/SQL: ORA-00947: insufficient values
```

What should I do to correct these errors? I changed some names from my code because it's an assignment and I having troubles trying to do it without errors.

Comment: You haven't declared a local variable called `ID`? The 'too many values' and 'insufficient values' errors seem fairly self-explanatory - just count the number of columns/values in each part of those statements.

Comment: `What should I do to correct these errors? ` best answer is learn the basics. There are are so many errors. And most of them would give you a clue on reading the message itself. All the best!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar, AlexPoole, I know that I had some little errors that I didn't see before (I'm a novice ><). And well, I didn't find the cause of my errors until I asked here for help. Thank you very much for your answers too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
10/38    PLS-00201: 'ID' must be declared
```

You're selecting data into a local variable `ID` that hasn't been declared.  If you want to declare a local variable, you'd do so in the declaration section between the `AS` and the `BEGIN`

```
   PROCEDURE create_emp(p_last_name IN employees.last_name%type, 
                        p_first_name IN    employees.first_name%type, 
                        p_email IN employees.email%type, 
                        p_hire_date IN  employees.hire_date%type, 
                        p_job_id IN employees.job_id%type) 
   AS
     id integer;
   BEGIN
     SELECT emp_sequence.NEXTVAL INTO id FROM dual;
```

If you're going to do that, you'd want to use the local variable `id` in your `INSERT` statement rather than calling `emp_sequence.nextval` directly.  Personally, though, I'd get rid of the local variable, get rid of the initial `SELECT`, and just make the `emp_sequence.nextval` call in your `INSERT` statement.

```
11/17    PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
```

Regardless of how you do it, though, you'd need the number of columns in your `INSERT` to match the number of `VALUES` you specify.

```
   PROCEDURE create_emp(p_last_name IN employees.last_name%type, 
                        p_first_name IN    employees.first_name%type, 
                        p_email IN employees.email%type, 
                        p_hire_date IN  employees.hire_date%type, 
                        p_job_id IN employees.job_id%type) 
   AS
     id integer;
   BEGIN
     SELECT emp_sequence.NEXTVAL INTO id FROM dual;
     INSERT INTO employees(employee_id, last_name, first_name, email, hire_date, job_id)
       VALUES (id, p_last_name, p_first_name, p_email, p_hire_date, p_job_id);
  END create_emp;
```

Or if you want to call the sequence directly

```
   PROCEDURE create_emp(p_last_name IN employees.last_name%type, 
                        p_first_name IN    employees.first_name%type, 
                        p_email IN employees.email%type, 
                        p_hire_date IN  employees.hire_date%type, 
                        p_job_id IN employees.job_id%type) 
   AS
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO employees(employee_id, last_name, first_name, email, hire_date, job_id)
       VALUES ( emp_sequence.NEXTVAL, p_last_name, p_first_name, p_email, p_hire_date, p_job_id);
  END create_emp;
```

Similarly, for your next error, the number of variables that you fetch into should match the number of columns that you're selecting

```
51/5     PL/SQL: ORA-00947: insufficient values
```

In your read_emp, you're selecting 7 things and trying to put them into 6 variables.  Assuming that you don't want to return the `employee_id`, don't bother selecting it.

```
   PROCEDURE read_emp(p_employee_id IN employees.employee_id%type, 
                      p_last_name OUT  employees.last_name%type, 
                      p_first_name OUT employees.first_name%type, 
                      p_email OUT  employees.email%type, 
                      p_hire_date OUT  employees.hire_date%type, 
                      p_job_id OUT  employees.job_id%type, 
                      p_salary OUT employees.salary%type) 
   AS
   BEGIN
     SELECT last_name, first_name, email, hire_date, job_id, salary
     INTO  p_last_name, p_first_name, p_email, p_hire_date, p_job_id, p_salary
     FROM EMPLOYEES
     WHERE employee_id = p_employee_id;
   END read_emp;
```

While you can write a `read_emp` procedure like this, it would generally make more sense to create a function that returns an `employees%rowtype` record instead.

Your exception clauses should be removed.  At best, they are discarding the error stack that would tell a person what failed and where.  At worst, they're hiding the errors (you should never assume that anyone will ever see anything that you write to `dbms_output`) and causing the calling code to believe that some operation succeeded when it didn't.

Comment: Whoa, I had too many little errors, I'm very ashamed! Thank you very much for help me and for your advice. I put the exceptions because I'm learning to use that :)