# Oracle errors for Package Body -PLS-00905: object REV123 is invalid

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to create a package as below. Took the reference from [Errors creating Oracle package body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386240/errors-creating-oracle-package-body) and https://www.guru99.com/packages-pl-sql.html.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY rev123
is
procedure p_get_x ( p_id  in NUMBER)
    is
          cursor c_get_x is
          select 
                rst.id,
                rst.col1,
                rst.col2          
          from REV_STAGE_TBL rst
          where not exists (select 1 from rev_tbl_1 fed
                           where  rst.id = fed.id);
          t_get_x c_get_x%rowtype; 
begin
   open c_get_x;
   fetch c_get_x bulk collect into t_get_x ;
   close c_get_x;


for idx in 1 .. t_get_x.count
  loop
    insert into rev_tbl_2
     (
      id,
      col1,
      col2 
     )
     values (
     t_get_x(idx).id,
     t_get_x(idx).col1,
     t_get_x(idx).col2
     );
end loop;
commit;
end p_get_x;
end rev123;    
/
```

Errors:

```
show error;


Package body REV123 compiled

Errors: check compiler log
Errors for PACKAGE BODY REV123:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/       PLS-00905: object REV123 is invalid
1/       PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'REV123' without its specification
```

Total numbers of rows to be copied is 5 Million.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a package body. It can't exist without package specification.

Before running the above code, create spec as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE rev123
is
  procedure p_get_x ( p_id  in NUMBER);
END;
/
```

Then

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY rev123
is
  procedure p_get_x ( p_id  in NUMBER)
  is
    cursor c_get_x is
    select ...
```

Comment: With the package it gives the same error

Comment: Which means that you did something wrong. Please, edit your initial message and post both package spec and body.

Comment: Okay I solved it  by adding :  t_get_x c_get_x%rowtype; 
      TYPE tab_get_x IS TABLE OF t_get_x%TYPE;
      tb_get_x tab_get_x;

Comment: OK; I'm glad you fixed it.